# update query in sql by comparing two tables

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server

i want to update the value of table1.data_plan by  the value in table2.data_plan for the same 
msisdn.
my table looks like this

- msisdn data_plan
- XXXX         YYY
- RRRR         SSSS
- msisdn data_plan
- XXXX         NNN
- RRRR         SSSS

what basically i have to do here is udate the first table data_plan to NNN

my code looks like this

```
UPDATE msisdn m FULL JOIN t1 a ON a.msidn=m.msidn AND a.data_plan != m.data_plan SET m.data_plan = a.data_plan
```

Answer (score 2):

As you've tagged under sql-server I'm posting a solution as sql-server answer.

```
update t1
set    t1.data_plan = t2.data_plan
from   table1 t1 inner join table2 t2
on     t1.msisdn = t2.msisdn
```

Answer (score 0):

you can also use sub query.

```
update table1 t1 
set data_plan= (select data_plan 
                from table2 t2 
                where t1.msisdn=t2.msisdn)
```

Comment: but this code doesnt work for large values.. say 200,000 records.

Comment: but this code is not efficient for large values in the tables.. say 200,000 rows. insteaad of inserting for every same msisdn in two tables can we update only if there is a change in the data_plan in the record so that the time taken to execut ethe query is less